# CookieContainer causes error with HttpWebResponse request.GetResponse() in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies

I'm using Basic Authentication to retrieve xml order information from a website.  The website endpoint url receives the authentication and then redirects to an url with the order information.  I can successfully authenticate but not retrieve the order information (I get a blank page, with status 200.  NOTE:  This is the same result I get in a browser if I navigate directly to the redirected url without first go to the url which handles authentication).  I believe this is because I need to handle the authentication cookie.  However, as soon as I add a cookie container to my request, request.GetResponse() bombs with an internal server error 500.

I have tested the url endpoint using Fiddler, and I get the same result as when I don't add a cookie container to my request.  Authentication is successful, and then the redirected page is blank with status code 200.  (P.S.  I can tell from Fiddler that the cookie is HttpOnly)

However, if I use a web browser and enter credentials at the initial url, it redirects to the order page with order content displayed.

**Question 1:  How can I determine (or further troubleshoot) if this is a problem with my code or with the order endpoint?**

**Question 2:  If it's a problem with my code, how should I handle the cookie?**

My code:

```
public void Main()
{
  Uri endpointUri = new Uri(Dts.Variables["User::endpointUrl"].Value.ToString());
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUri);
  request.Method = "GET";  //I have also tried POST
  request.KeepAlive = true;
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
  SetBasicAuthHeader(request, Dts.Variables["User::endpointUsername"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::endpointPassword"].Value.ToString());

  request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();  //If I comment out this line, the error does not occur, but I also don't see any order info.

  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    Debug.WriteLine((new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream)).ReadToEnd());
    return;
  }
}

    public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest req, String userName, String userPassword)
    {
        string authInfo = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(userName + ":" + userPassword));
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
    }
```

The error:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Did you try setting the content type of your request? In theory if you do not set your content type you should get a 400 (bad request), but I don't know nothing about your server-side...

Comment: I tried setting the content and that did not impact the result.

Comment: What about using the UserAgent? request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";

Comment: Setting the user agent results in the same thing.  Error 500 when cookie container is used, and a blank page when there is no cookie container.